How do I send a pdf through a multipart post request?
I am specifically having an issue where I send pdf data through a multipart request and it ends up on the other end either: still encrypted, or completely blank.
I am contacting an external API through a node server I am running. I was given an endpoint to send the pdf file to, through a multipart request. Here is the example documentation I was given for the body of the multipart request...
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="patient_id"

3
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="medical_file_category_id"

2
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="report.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy
MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAABAAEDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AL+AD//Z

I have created a function on my node server and will provide two different outcomes resulting from small code changes because I thought these two conclusions may provide some insight into helping with an answer to my question.
The first function is...
async function postDocuments(document) {
    let mData = fs.readFileSync(document)
    const data = `--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="patient_id"

110
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="medical_file_category_id"

7
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test_10.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

${mData}
--BOUNDARY--`

    const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY' } }
    const response = await instance.post('/medical-records/medical-files', data, options)
    console.log('Status: ', response.status)
    console.log('Headers: ', response.headers)
    console.log('Response: ', response.data)
}

In this first implementation I am creating a multipart request that does not send encoded data, this results in the file ending up on the server completely blank.
Here is the 2nd implementation...
async function postDocuments(document) {
    let base64Data = fs.readFileSync(document, { encoding: 'base64' })
    const data = `--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="patient_id"

110
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="medical_file_category_id"

7
--BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test_10.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
content-transfer-encoding: base64

${base64Data}
--BOUNDARY--`

    const options = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY' } }
    const response = await instance.post('/medical-records/medical-files', data, options)
    console.log('Status: ', response.status)
    console.log('Headers: ', response.headers)
    console.log('Response: ', response.data)
}

With the 2nd approach, the file ends up with nothing but the encoded string on the pdf.
Again what is causing the file to not have the data showing properly on the pdf or at all?

What you are saying is very interesting and I did notice this. You are referring to the example multipart/request provided by the api owner. I have sent them a message asking why they use a jpeg file when the request specifies pdf and the documentation is also noted to be used for pdfs. My encoded data is however a pdf. Thank you for the response though @KJ !
